# ion-datetime does not display initial date

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic2, ionic3

ion-datetime does not display initial date

**home.html**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" min="2018" max="2100" formControlName="date_of_delivery" placeholder="Select date of delivary"
        class="dateBorder"></ion-datetime>
```

**home.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.generalDetailForm.controls['date_of_delivery'].patchValue("16/11/2011")
}
```

does not display my given value
Where is the mistake?

***Please help and thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ngModel` for data binding.

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

      myForm: FormGroup;
      date;

      constructor() {

        this.myForm = new FormGroup({

          date_of_delivery: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])

        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {

         this.date = "2011-11-16";
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <ion-datetime 
      displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
      formControlName="date_of_delivery" 
      placeholder="Select date of delivary" 
      [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>

</form>
```

> Update

If you want to set value to `ion-datetime` using form control `patchValue` use `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
ngOnInit() {

 this. generalDetailForm.controls['date_of_delivery'].patchValue("2011-11-16");
}
```

See updated example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ehkc42?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html).

Comment: @Apple developer is this answer is not working for you?

Comment: why i need formData?

Comment: `formData` is not a must but when we have a lot of form fields it is useful to have `formData` when sending data to server APIs. In your case it is not needed. I removed it and check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but my question is little different as you can read, i want to set value to form control and not to model. because in next page i am passing form data for further use.

Comment: Awesome bro it works... but the thing is i have not defined ion-datetime format as ''yyyy-MM-dd" then why i need to pass in same format?

Comment: The reason may be acceptable date format for `ion-datetime` using `patchValue` is "yyyy-MM-dd". If my answer worked for you please accept it.

Comment: Possibly right ur words are, but i am receiving date in 'DD/MM/YYYY' from server how do i convert it then?